# How to exclude files from compilation in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, directory

I have a project that builds several similar apps, different apps require different resources. I have folder **assets/images_project1** and **images/project2**. How can I exclude e.g. **images/project2** from the compilation? I don't want to manually replace the folders every time. If files still, they increase the app size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60440129/exclude-assets-from-debug-build-on-flutter) there is no built-in solution as of right now.

But the easiest thing to do is just manually comment folder in `pubspec.yaml` under the `assets` section.

Optionally you can use script from the mentioned question.